# homebrew gcc-5 fails to find any standard library

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew, gcc

I am running os x version el capitan and have installed gcc5 via homebrew. However, compiling simple programs such as:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

leads to following error:

```
hello.c:1:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

This is the case for any other standard c library, such as time.h.

I've been reading around concerning where gcc looks to link against library, and according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939930/finding-out-what-the-gcc-include-path-is I can get the list in the following manner:

```
echo | gcc-5 -Wp, -v
```

Which results in following paths:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc-5
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/5.2.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0/5.2.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0

Configured with: ../configure
--build=x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0 --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/5.2.0
--libdir=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/5.2.0/lib/gcc/5
--enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran --program-suffix=-5
--with-gmp=/usr/local/opt/gmp --with-mpfr=/usr/local/opt/mpfr
--with-mpc=/usr/local/opt/libmpc --with-isl=/usr/local/opt/isl
--with-system-zlib --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes
--enable-stage1-checking --enable-checking=release --enable-lto
--with-build-config=bootstrap-debug --disable-werror
--with-pkgversion='Homebrew gcc 5.2.0'
--with-bugurl=https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues
--enable-plugin --disable-nls --enable-multilib

Thread model: posix

gcc version 5.2.0 (Homebrew gcc 5.2.0)
```

Doing it for the os x gcc compiler, I get the following:

```
clang -cc1 version 7.0.0 based upon LLVM 3.7.0svn default target
x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include"

ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/local/include"

ignoring nonexistent directory
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/Library/Frameworks"

include "..." search starts here:

include <...> search starts here:  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/7.0.0/include

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks
(framework directory)
End of search list.
```

I do not know what these outputs mean, nor where my standard libraries are located. Could anybody help me configure gcc5 correctly?

Comment: `xcode-select --install`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is wrong with installation. Try updating Homebrew and reinstalling gcc-5. On El Capitan

`Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0`

should be

`Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0`

Works fine for me.

Comment: How do I change the target for gcc?

Comment: Never mind, I performed brew update, brew upgrade and reinstalled gcc-5, now I works. Thanks